# How to load data into static_placeholder

Tags: django-cms

Running python 3.6 and Django-Cms 3.5

I have read the docs here: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/templates_placeholders.html

But I'm confused about how to how to actually add data to the `static_placeholder`

i have

```
<footer>
  {% static_placeholder "footer" %}
</footer>
```

Where does this gets loaded from?  My footer is html/bootstrap4, so everything would get moved based on screen size. The only way i can see to add this is via a snippet, and in this i can't use `{% static ... %}` calls in those snippets.  The text plugin is not sufficient.

I'm pretty sure i'm missing something obvious.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can load default plugins to a placeholder and this may suit your needs, but bare in mind that by nature a static placeholder is the same on all pages across a site so usually when you setup a site you'd populate that placeholder with plugins.

So if default plugins would work, you can do something like the following in your [`CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF`](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/reference/configuration.html#cms-placeholder-conf);

```
CMS_PLACEHOLDER_CONF = {
    'content': {
        "plugins": ['TextPlugin'],
        'excluded_plugins': ['InheritPlugin'],
    },
    'footer': {
        'plugins': ['TextPlugin', 'PicturePlugin'],
        'text_only_plugins': ['LinkPlugin'],
        'name': gettext("Footer"),
        'default_plugins': [
            {
                'plugin_type': 'TextPlugin',
                'values': {
                    'body':'<p>site design / logo © 2018 My Inc</p>',
                },
            },
        ],
        'child_classes': {
            'TextPlugin': ['PicturePlugin', 'LinkPlugin'],
        },
        'parent_classes': {
            'LinkPlugin': ['TextPlugin'],
        },
    },
```